# RegEx for a^b instead of pow(a,b)

Tags: javascript, regex

Here's an interesting one. Anyone have a good RegEx for converting all (first) ^ (second) to Math.pow((first), (second))?

EDIT:

The best I have so far is

```
s = s.replace(/((?:\d+\.?\d*)|\w+|\((?:(?:[^\(\)]*(?:\([^\(\)]*\)))*)\))\s*\^\s*((?:\d+\.?\d*)|\w+|\((?:(?:[^\(\)]*(?:\([^\(\)]*\)))*)\))/g, 'Math.pow($1, $2)') // replace expression ^ expression with Math.pow($1, $2)
```

The answers so far are not general enough. They don't cover something like (var1 + var2)^2 let alone (var1 * (var2 + var3))^2

The solution will have to work with parentheses.

You can use strfriend.com to help visualize the regex as you make it.  That's what I've been doing.

Comment: And the closest you have right now is ...?

Comment: What should `a * b ^ c` convert to? `a ^ b + c`? `a ^ b ^ c`?

Comment: This can't be done with normal regex. It requires arbitrary recursion.  If you want an answer I suggest you raise the bounty, this is a fairly involved problem.

Comment: What you need is a lexical expression parser...

Comment: It's been a while, but I believe matching arbitrary parenthesis/quotes/chatacters in general fall outside of being a regular language and therefore cannot be parsed by a regular exression.

Comment: @Anon.: The exponentiation operator is typically right-associative.

Comment: Let me phrase this simply: Regex is not a tool to evaluate math, or "convert" math to a string you can run eval over. What do you do when I come along and ask you to do this: `(0^1*9^(1^9^0^(0.1)))^(1/(8^2))` ? You're screwed, that's what. Don't do it.

Comment: @Anon. that is fairly well defined, `a * b ^ c -> a * (b ^ c)`, `a ^ b + c -> (a ^ b) + c` and `a ^ b ^ c -> ((a ^ b) ^ c)`. All these follow the standard rules of PEDMAS.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This cannot be done with regex (at least not without lots of effort). You have to consider different layers of parenthesis, which can't be handled with a simple regular expression. I suggest to look for a library capable of parsing mathematical expression. Or you'll have to restrict the possible expression to something you can handle with a simple regex.

There is the possibility to define named and balancing capture groups in a regular expression which can be used (backreferenced) in the same regular expression. With this you would have to define the desired subset of the math syntax and both captures for the parameters. I suggest you should not reinvent the wheel and use a JS library.

http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2207

Comment: Mattias is right here; if you have a language with nested constructs like parens, then a regular language just won't cut it -- in fact, its there in the definition of 'regular language'. Better to start writing a parser, or finding one of the many out there.

Comment: http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2207 is dead, could you please update?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `String.replace`:

```
> s = "hello 2^3 pow!"
> s.replace(/(\d+)\^(\d+)/, "Math.pow($1, $2)")
"hello Math.pow(2, 3) pow!"
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to convert source files or something like that, take a perl script running over your source files and use [Math::Expression::Evaluator::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/~moritz/Math-Expression-Evaluator-v0.3.2/lib/Math/Expression/Evaluator/Parser.pm). From the synopsis:

```
use Math::Expression::Evaluator::Parser;

my $exp = '2 + a * 4';
my $ast = Math::Expression::Evaluator::Parser::parse($exp, {});
# $ast is now something like this:
# $ast = ['+',
#          2,
#         ['*',
#          ['$', 'a'],
#          4
#         ]
#        ];
```

Looks like it can handle exponentiations easily. So the AST in your case would be something like:

```
# $ast = ['^',
#         base,
#         exp
#        ];
```

You could build the desired expression 'Math.pow(base, exp)' by (recursively) reassemble a string from the 'base' and 'exp' subtrees.

If you want to implement a calculator in JavaScript then you need of course a [JavaScript-Parser](http://silentmatt.com/javascript-expression-evaluator/) or you could rely on a server-backend implemented using Math::Expression::Evaluator.

Comment: This, or an answer that discusses implementing similar functionality in JS is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

The bad news: regular expressions won't cut it (as many answers indicate), you will need to write a parser for this.

The good news: you can relatively easily do this yourself in almost any language by writing a recursive descent parser. You should of course reuse existing code as much as possible, but coding a recursive descent parser yourself (and seeing how you encode precedence rules) can be recommended purely for the enlightening experience.

Pick up any book on compiler construction and read the first few chapters on parsing. Let me recommend [this freely available book](http://www-old.oberon.ethz.ch/WirthPubl/CBEAll.pdf) by Niklaus Wirth, look for 4.1 "The method of recursive descent".

Answer (score 1):

```
var caretReplace = function(_s) {
    if (_s.indexOf("^") > -1) {
        var tab = [];
        var powfunc="Math.pow";
        var joker = "___joker___";
        while (_s.indexOf("(") > -1) {
            _s = _s.replace(/(\([^\(\)]*\))/g, function(m, t) {
                tab.push(t);
                return (joker + (tab.length - 1));
            });
        }

        tab.push(_s);
        _s = joker + (tab.length - 1);
        while (_s.indexOf(joker) > -1) {
            _s = _s.replace(new RegExp(joker + "(\\d+)", "g"), function(m, d) {
                return tab[d].replace(/(\w*)\^(\w*)/g, powfunc+"($1,$2)");
            });
        }
    }
    return _s;
};
```

1. `console.log(caretReplace("(3*(f(x^2)-2)^2+1^5-g(2^3+1)^5)^(9-2^3)"));`
   gives `Math.pow((3*Math.pow((f(Math.pow(x,2))-2),2)+Math.pow(1,5)-Math.pow(g(Math.pow(2,3)+1),5)),(9-Math.pow(2,3)))`.
2. Your math expression must be valid, with well balanced opened and closed parentheses.
3. You can replace `Math.pow` with any function name you want.
4. I've done this by replacing all parentheses, from the most inner to the most outer, with non-math texts (`___joker___0`, `___joker___1`, etcetera). At the end I parse all these strings hierarchically, to replace carets on non-parentheses expressions.

Comment: You might enhance it a bit by removing excess parentheses if you match optional parentheses in the pattern. [Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zmr531wb/6/).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Jison, a Javascript parser generator.

In particular, check out their [calculator demo](http://zaach.github.com/jison/demos/calc/)