# Rewrite formula string to replace a^b with Math.pow(a, b)

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

I'm at the moment trying to plot formulas on HTML5 `<canvas>` by letting the user put in a formula. This works great through `eval()`; however, the `^` means bitwise XOR in Javascript, while it should mean 'to the power of' in a formula.

So basically I'd have to rewrite something like `x^4` to `Math.pow(x, 4)`. I came up with using regular expressions. This one however only works to a certain extent:

`"x^4".replace(/(.*)\^(.*)/g, "Math.pow($1, $2)")`

It does rewrite `x^4` to `Math.pow(x, 4)`, but for more advanced formulas this goes wrong. For example, `2 + x^4` is rewritten as `Math.pow(2 + x, 4)`, while it should of course be `2 + Math.pow(x, 4)`. Moreover, if the exponent has brackets around it, e.g. `2^(x+1) + 3`, it should be rewritten to `Math.pow(2, x+1) + 3` instead of `Math.pow(2, x+1 + 3)`, of course.

How would I go about rewriting this so that only the correct parts are put into the pow function? I really do not see where to start, so any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your regular expression will need to be a little more thorough to accommodate coefficients as well. You should probably have it check for whitespace in front of and behind a variable and also separate coefficients from variables by injecting `*`. You'll also have to implement the same grammar rules indicated by the `()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx for a^b instead of pow(a,b)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777685/regex-for-ab-instead-of-powa-b)

Comment: @Joel thanks for your hints.

@Ben sorry didn't see that one, thanks.

Comment: — No worries!  I just wanted to make sure you didn't miss the info contained in the answers there.  :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a tricky one. What you're talking about here is an expression parser.

You might want to take a look at [Jison](http://zaach.github.com/jison/), which is designed to help people solve this type of problem.

Regular expressions aren't really the best way to do parsing of tokenized strings. [One of Jison's demos](http://zaach.github.com/jison/demos/calc/) is *precisely* what you're looking for, in terms of expression parsing, leaving you to work on the fun stuff of function graphing.

Comment: Actually, this also seems *much* faster than `eval` for some reason!

Comment: Thanks for the link to that calculator. But the grammar is flawed, it says -2^2 equals 4 when it should actually be -4 as wolfram alpha and google state. By the way, MS Excel has the same error, it gives 4.

Comment: @keithphw, actually, that expression is not uniquely defined. It can be interpreted mathematically as (-2)^2 or -(2^2). In a programming language, it is well defined by the operator precedence table. In math, it's more a matter of convention and, in this case, there isn't a clear convention here

Comment: Thanks for your reply Dan. I think there is a convention though, order of operations. Power comes before both subtraction and multiply (by negative one). MS excel is the only outlier in all of the major programs that I know of. By the way, what edit would you make to the Jison demo to make it give -2^2 = -4?

Comment: It looks like the precedence of negation is currently the highest one. I would move that one to be next to multiplication and have exponentiation as the highest precedence

Answer (score 5):

```
    var caretReplace = function(_s) {
    if (_s.indexOf("^") > -1) {
        var tab = [];
        var powfunc="Math.pow";
        var joker = "___joker___";
        while (_s.indexOf("(") > -1) {
            _s = _s.replace(/(\([^\(\)]*\))/g, function(m, t) {
                tab.push(t);
                return (joker + (tab.length - 1));
            });
        }

        tab.push(_s);
        _s = joker + (tab.length - 1);
        while (_s.indexOf(joker) > -1) {
            _s = _s.replace(new RegExp(joker + "(\\d+)", "g"), function(m, d) {
                return tab[d].replace(/(\w*)\^(\w*)/g, powfunc+"($1,$2)");
            });
        }
    }
    return _s;
};
```

1. console.log(caretReplace("(3*(f(x^2)-2)^2+1^5-g(2^3+1)^5)^(9-2^3)"));
   gives : Math.pow((3*Math.pow((f(Math.pow(x,2))-2),2)+Math.pow(1,5)-Math.pow(g(Math.pow(2,3)+1),5)),(9-Math.pow(2,3)))
2. Your math expression must be with well balanced opened and closed parenthesis (valid expression).
3. You can replace "Math.pow" by any function name you want.
4. I've done this by replacing all parenthesis, from the most inner to the most outer, with  non-math texts ("**_joker**_0","**_joker**_1", etc...). At the end I parse all theses strings hierarchically, to replace carets on non parenthesis expressions.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt this is even doable with regex. The regex flavor in JS doesn't support recursive patterns (and it would be extremely cumbersome to do it even with that), so you're out of luck with complex expressions such as `((x + 2) * 3)^(x ^ (2 * x))`.

If you want to be able to do transformations like this on the expression, you'll probably have to use a proper tokenizer and parser in order to get the structure out of it.

Answer (score 1):

Typically this type of problem is approached using [lexers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) and [parsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing), not regexes.  Because of the order of operations of the mathematical expressions, you need to understand the whole expression (and all of its parts), not just the power-of portion.  I am not sure which parsers are generally used for Javascript, but it seems ANTLR has a target for generating Javascript parsers: http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/ANTLR3JavaScriptTarget