# Javascript : find regexp with capture to replace a^b by Math.pow(a, b)

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, pow

My string is the follow :

```
str = "(2+2)^(4*(5+6^(5^6))))";
```

As you can see, the power can be nested inside another power with or without parenthesis.

So I want to convert this string by using regexp to replace ^ by Math.pow(a,b) of javascript.

An idea ? Thank you very much in advance, cordially.

Comment: How about putting it on a text editor and use find/replace?

Comment: And then you can use `ev[ai]l` on it

Comment: Tushar : ev[ai]l : that is say ?

Comment: Do you actually need to use a regex or is this just the way that you are trying to solve the problem?

Comment: @pedromss : the string is typed freely by user in input text.

Comment: @markt : yes I need a regexp, it's very difficult because the user can type many pow nested.
The "^" character doesn't behave like pow, so I must use Math.pow(a, b).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rewrite formula string to replace a^b with Math.pow(a, b)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901490/rewrite-formula-string-to-replace-ab-with-math-powa-b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that using a regex to parse expressions will not turn out well for you...

Why not use an math expression parser library like http://mathjs.org/

Comment: Yes it's a good idea. 
But why using a regex to parse expressions will not turn out well for me ?

Comment: It's not a simple find & replace. To parse reliably, you will need to do multiple passes and have code that is context aware of association and priority. Someone else has already done the hard work for you. Use a library :P

Comment: Yes, you're right, handling priority and association in formula is very hard. My aim is to create a calculator in javascript. I hope mathjs suits.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Actually the problem is that this is a recursive structure, non regular. JS regex does not support the PCRE recursive parameter `(?R)`

Comment: You can definitely do it, but if you're going to code the logic yourself, a common approach is to build a parse tree by tokenizing the input and then evaluate that.

Comment: @Tivie It can be done without the recursive parameter, not using regex. It's just so ridiculously complicated, you may as well use as a library that has already done the job (especially as OP wants to create a calculator anyway).

Answer (score 1):

These are the steps your algorithm would have to perform:

1. Find the "root `^`" char
2. Capture the groups before and after `^`
3. Repeat

The problem here is that this type of data structure is both recursive and non regular...

- It's recursive since you can have an infinite number of nested parenthesis, and each needs to be evaluated separately
- It's non regular since, for instance, you can have groups that don't have parenthesis: `(2+2)^2`

...which makes finding the said "root `^`" problematic

Also, the input might not always be valid (for instance, user forgets to close a parenthesis).